# Code Snippets and intelliSense in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, code-snippets

I created some code snippets for our `javascript` development in `Visual Studio 2012`.
From what I see, it is possible to use `intelliSense` to include custom snippets for `c#` and `vb` scripts, so that the snippets are accessible by `CTRL+SPACE`.

But if I add my snippets for `javascript`, they are only accessible when I type `CTRL+K+X`. Is there a way to simplify this and make them accessible via `CTRL+SPACE`?

**My Snippet:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippet Format="1.1.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <Header>
    <Title>MySnippet</Title>
    <Author>Me</Author>
    <Shortcut>short_cut</Shortcut>
    <Description>This is my snippet</Description>
    <SnippetTypes>
      <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
      <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
    </SnippetTypes>
  </Header>
  <Snippet>
    <Declarations>
      <Literal>
        <ID>name</ID>
        <ToolTip>Name of the var</ToolTip>
        <Default>name</Default>
      </Literal>
    </Declarations>
    <Code Language="JavaScript">
      <![CDATA[
    it.doIt = function () {
      var $name$ = 4;
      // some content
      $selected$$end$
    };]]>
    </Code>
  </Snippet>
</CodeSnippet>
```

Comment: In your snippet, make sure your language is set to javascript like so: `<Code Language="javascript">code snippet here</Code>`

Comment: I just updated my question and added the snippet I want to include. It already contains the part that you mentioned.